# In 18th century England, was "eat" the past tense of "eat" and how was it pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

In Boswell's *London Journal* (1762-3), the author expresses the past tense of the verb *eat* with the same spelling:

> I sat in till between four and five. I then went to Holborn, to a cheesemonger's, and bought a piece of 3 lb. 10 oz., which cost me 14 1/2d. I **eat** part of it in the shop, with a halfpenny roll, two of which I had bought at a baker's. [emphasis mine]

This makes me wonder at the pronunciation, as I have wondered before. When I first read the journals back in college, I mentally pronounced them the way we say the current present tense verb. Then I decided he must have pronounced it  /ˈeɪt/ rhyming it with *ate*. So far so good.

Now I wonder if the word might have been pronounced /ˈɛt/ (rhyming with *bet*) the way some British and rural Americans have it.

The word *eat* itself comes from OE *etan* by way of ME *eten*, which would suggest that it might have at least for some time rhymed with *ate*.

Note too the past tense of some verbs are identical in spelling to the present tense (e.g., *read*/*read*), though pronounced differently.

Can someone cast a bit of light on this?

Comment: “*The historically justified variant is ate homonymous with eight, and therefore it does not come as a surprise that the colonists took this old pronunciation to the New World. The origin of the pronunciation et for “ate” is not quite clear. There may have been the Middle English form ēt, which underwent shortening. Since both variants have been known in England for centuries, their coexistence in America need not surprise us either.*” https://blog.oup.com/2019/12/some-of-our-basic-verbs-eat/

Comment: Fascinating!  Reading 'ate' I say (BrEng) both /ɛt/ and /eɪt/ depending on context (textual and social).  "Is there any cake left?"  "No, I ate it all yesterday".  'Eat' pronounced /ɛt/  sounds very plausible

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, **eat** (pronounced /it/ and possibly /ɛt/) was a past tense form of "eat" in English until the 1800s and more recently in Scotland.

The OED lists a range of past tense forms of eat. The relevant ones are

> 1500s–1600s **eate**, 1600s–1800s **eat**, 1500s– **ate**

So "eat" (/it/) was a past tense form of "eat" in Boswell's time, although "ate" was also possible.

The OED also suggests the non-standard past-tense form "et" (/ɛt/) may relate to "eat" rather than "ate", by analogy with other past tense forms "read" (/rɛt/), "led" (from "lead"), etc.

The OED does not give a geographical range for the variants. The *Scottish National Dictionary* has citations of the /it/ form as late as the 20th century, including from Aberdeen in 1925

> Peter, my neeper, mairriet a wife An' cudna keep 'er, He stappit her intull a bole i' the wa', An the mice **eet** 'er.

This uses the spelling "eet" rather than "eat" but spelling in Scots is considerably more varied.

[James Boswell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Boswell) was of course a Scot, born in Edinburgh.

- "eat, v.". OED Online. March 2023. Oxford University Press. Accessed 22 May 2023. https://www-oed-com.nls.idm.oclc.org/view/Entry/59131
- "Eat v., n.". Dictionary of the Scots Language. 2004. Scottish Language Dictionaries Ltd. Accessed 22 May 2023. http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/eat

Comment: Should that top line read "*1500-1600s, 1600-1800s, 1800s-*" ?

Comment: I think you mean /rεd/ for _read_, since English does not generally have terminal devoicing. // @MadHatter No, it’s correct the way it is. It means that the spelling _eate_ is attested in the 1500s and 1600s, the spelling _eat_ is attested in the 1600s, 1700s and 1800s, and the spelling _ate_ is attested from the 1500s onwards.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am grateful for the clarification; thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. In addition to the answer citing the Oxford English Dictionary, Johnson's *Dictionary of the English Language* (1755) [also lists both *ate* and *eat*](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/views/search.php?term=eat) as the preterite (past tense) form of *eat*:

> To EAT. *v.a.* preterite *ate*, or *eat*; part. *eat*, or *eaten*. [*etan*, Sax. *itan*, Gothick; *eich*, Erse.]

As for pronunciation, in John Walker's *A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary and Expositor of the English Language* (1791) (found in [Eighteenth Century Collections Online](https://www.gale.com/primary-sources/eighteenth-century-collections-online); subscription needed), he claims that to *eat* is pronounced with a long /i/ but that the past tense form is usually pronounced *et* (/ɛt/):

> The first sound of ea is like open e, and is heard in the following words: - *Afeard, anneal, appeal, appear [...] easy, to eat, eaten, eaves [...]*
> (p. 28)
>
> The preterimperfect tense of *eat* is sometimes written *ate*, particularly by Lord Bolingbroke, and frequently, and, perhaps, more correctly, pronounced *et*, especially in Ireland; but *eaten* always preserved the *ea* long. (p. 29)

Comment: As a BrE speaker I do pronounce 'ate' as 'et'.

Comment: _Eich_ is a truly bizarre way to write the Irish verb, which has been written _ith_ since Old Irish times nearly a millennium before Johnson. As it happens, while some forms of the Irish verb are cognate with _eat_, the present stem in _ith-_ is not (though it is, quite distantly, cognate with _fat_ and the name _Ireland_), so it’s not even a valid example – but Johnson couldn’t know that in the 18th century when most Celtic sound laws were yet to be discovered.

Answer (score 2):

Here in Yorkshire /ˈɛt/ is commonly used in Yorkshire dialect.  And the past participle is /ˈɛtn/ (I think I've transcribed that correctly).  Even people who don't speak dialect usually sing the last but one verse of the song "on Ilkley Moor baht 'at" using /ˈɛtn/, usually written "etten". (Then we shall all have etten thee...)

Comment: The Yorkshire dialect was widely represented in 18th century British literature, and has not changed much since then.

Comment: Yorkshire dialect IS a form of British English.  As barbecue says it hasn't changed much since the 18th century.  I find it fascinating how much English has changed in some areas of the UK and not in others.